# Diana Q-R time frame?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've noticed when playing Diana that if you Q lands slightly after your R it still resets your R.

Is this because of one of the following or because a time-frame is allotted, if so is the time-frame known?

- Misconception of when Q & R 'hits' the target. Possible misconception seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Do8eFYxomU) (YouTube video).
- Latency
- Combination of both
- Something else

Comment: It looks like the q procs before the ultimate but the animation isn't quick enough to accurately show this in game. Neat trick though!

Comment: i dont think it has to do with latency because if you have a constant latency then both inputs will arrive at the server with the same delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer after some partially related searches.

"The time it takes for  Crescent Strike to reach your target at max range is the same time  Lunar Rush takes to reach so if you cast Crescent Strike into Lunar Rush you will get the cooldown refresh immediately."

It is a [wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Diana/Strategy) one could argue it is unreliable but I feel that same argument could be used to say StackExchange is unreliable haha. Assuming this is true then my thought that it was just a misconception of when the abilities 'hit' would be true. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered, but yeah, the "trick" is that the check for the Q stack happens after Diana reaches the enemy, so if a Q is mid-flight when you use R it reaches the target in time for the refresh to happen.

Be careful trying to "abuse" that: if opponent dashes out of Q range during your R, the Q will miss and you won't get the refresh.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to master the art of using R then Q mid-flight to guarantee hit. I've only done it successfully once on a player. (I can do it on minions but that's not really the goal haha).